# How to comment a include line using sed

Tags: regex, sed

I want to comment the below line in one of my header file using sed

```
#include <stdint-gcc.h>
```

I tried the following and it failed

```
sed -i 's/#include <stdint-gcc.h>///#include <stdint-gcc.h>/g' file.h
sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'
```

Can you please provide the exact line

Comment: Use alternate delimiter e.g. `~` : `sed -i 's~#include <stdint-gcc\.h>~//&~' file.h`

Comment: I get sed: -e expression #1, char 27: unknown option to `s'

Comment: Sorry, it works. Thanks